# Programatically Add a link to QuickLink App

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-dev-pnp, quick-links

Using Pnp (C#) to provision a modern page and adding a QuickLinks web part. 
But can't add links to the webpart.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If interested you can find the answer here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/77af4231-0a0f-441c-9ce9-74f8ecd7a474/programmatically-edit-quick-links?forum=sharepointdevelopment&prof=required